# PHP MySQL Syntax quotes dots

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm really confused about the difference and when should I write like that in MySQL queries between :

`` `".$variable." `` `

`' ".$variable." '`

`" '.$variable.' "`

`'$variable'`

In other words what's the rule of quotes, dots ...

Comment: [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: None of the above, use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: The dots are PHP string concatenators - nothing to do with MySQL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variable: $a

---

This is a string: "hello world"

---

This is a string: 'hello world'

---

You can join variables & strings by dot:

```
$b = $a . "hello" . $a . 'world';
```

or use variable inside " "

```
$b = "hello $a world" ;
$b = "hello" . $a . "world" ;
$b = 'hello' . $a . 'world' ;
```

---

You can not use variables inside '

---

` use in mysql for field & table titles.

---

' use in mysql for variables.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you build your query.

In example, I like to build my queries somewhat like this:

```
"SELECT name FROM table WHERE table_id='".$id."'"
```

The double quotes are to close (and later re-open) the statement, single quotes simply mean that it's something of a string (in my example I'm using an integer, but words should be encapsulated in single quotes). The dots are PHP-related: they simply connect/paste stuff together.

Hope my answer has been of use to you :)